# Is there a reason why I can't drop columns from a data frame on my R Gui on Mac

Tags: r, macos

I was using the following command:

```
data = files.tsb [-c(60:113)]
```

It's a huge dataset so if you want to check out my data you can download my workspace from here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ij1ahw23o944aar/prob

The problem only arise when I'm on R Gui but when I tried running it in the Mac terminal, it works fine. On R Gui, the rows are deleted instead of columns. I would've thought the problem is with my Gui but there's no problem when I use another data frame. This is my R version, if it helps: Version 3.0.2 2013-05-17.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not too eager to download your workspace (and I suspect I'm not the only one).  Can you reproduce the behavior with a smaller data set? If not, can you identify what the problem rows or columns are?

Comment: At the very least, post the error message you got -- or if no error message, what was "wrong" with the output.

Comment: There's no error message. Instead, rows are deleted. @CarlWitthoft.

Comment: As I've mentioned, it doesn't give the same problem on another data frame, hence I attach the original data in the link @Aaron

Comment: What does R output when you type `str(data)`?

Comment: [1] "data.table" "data.frame" @ScottRitchie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your comment, your `data` is actually a `data.table` not a `data.frame`, which uses an entirely different syntax.

To remove the columns of a `data.table`, you need to do the following:

```
data[, -c(60:113), with=FALSE]
```

Or you can simply convert it back to a `data.frame` first:

```
as.data.frame(data)[-c(60:113)]
```

Comment: Maybe it's worth to mention that if columns 60:113 are not further needed `data[, 60:113 := NULL, with=FALSE]` might be more performant.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot Scott. But I'm curious why it doesn't cause the same problem when I did it on the terminal? And why typing is.data.frame (data) gives a TRUE?

Comment: @Meed concerning your first question: because the code you executed in the GUI was probably not the same as the one you executed in the terminal. Concerning the second question: Because a `data.table` *is* a `data.frame` from an object oriented perspective.

Comment: @Meed As @Beasterfield said, a `data.table` is a `data.frame`. So if you haven't loaded the `data.table` library, `R` will treat it as a `data.frame`. In your terminal, the `data.table` library hasn't been loaded, while on your GUI it has.